# Where to find Ubuntu Server Edition for education?

Tags: server

I want to have some info about Ubuntu Server:
Is it free for all/education purposes?
Where can I find support (tutorials, complete guides, etc.)?
Any useful hints/ideas for using it in an educational setting?

Comment: What do you mean by _educational setting_? The support is around the internet, just ask a specific question.

Comment: Using it for teaching in a classroom.

Comment: Networking concepts:  basic setup, mail server, file server, etc.

Comment: I have found that a very useful assignment for learning network concepts is to have your students cobble up a client and a server program, in the programming language of your choice, and have them talk to each other in some meaningful way, introducing the concept of a *protocol*.

Comment: I agree with you. As this is part of a course in Operating Systems, they should focus more on network administration though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All Ubuntu flavours are completely free for all purposes. You are welcome to make a donation though.

You can find Ubuntu Server releases for download e.g. at https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server or http://releases.ubuntu.com/.

The official Ubuntu Server documentation can be found at https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/index.html, an installation guide at https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/install-ubuntu-server.

If you have specific questions, feel free to ask them here on Ask Ubuntu.